# openCV polygon detection

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

I am supposed to write a program to process images of this type:
[image]

(All images are of this format: green rectangles, and blue circles). The circles are representing the binary representation of the number. The task is to output the decimal number after detecting the circles.

My approach was to first find the green rectangle (I did not use colour masking, reason explained later) and obtain its width and height.

Next, I reasoned by symmetry that the centers of the circles must be at distances `w/8,3w/8,5w/8` and `7w/8` from the left edge of the rectangle. (Horizontally).

So, I used `HoughCircles()` method, and then tried to express the x-coordinates of the centers in the form `(2x-1)w/8`.
Clearly, the decimal equivalent of each circle is given by `exp=2^(4-x).`So, I used `n+=2**exp` to obtain the decmal representation.

I used the coordinates of the rectangle to also approximate the appropriate minRadius and maxRadius values for the HoughCircles() method, in order to not detect unnecessary circles.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread("7.jpeg")

img_height,img_w,c=img.shape


n=0 #stores the decimal rep.

width=0 #dimensions of the rectangle
height=0

start_x=0 #starting coordinates of the rectangle
start_y=0
end_x=0 #ending '''''''
end_y=0
     
minr=0 #for the houghCircles() method
maxr=0
mind=0

output = img.copy()
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


_, th = cv.threshold(gray, 240, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, _ = cv.findContours(th, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for contour in contours:
    approx = cv.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.01* cv.arcLength(contour, True), True)
    
    cv.drawContours(img, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 0), 5)
    x = approx.ravel()[0]
    y = approx.ravel()[1] 

    
    if len(approx) == 4 and x>15 :
        
        
        x1 ,y1, w, h = cv.boundingRect(approx)
        aspectRatio = float(w)/h
        if aspectRatio <= 0.95 or aspectRatio >= 1.05:

          
          width=w
          height=h
          start_x=x1
          start_y=y1
          end_x=start_x+width
          end_y=start_y+height
          cv.rectangle(output, (start_x,start_y), (end_x,end_y), (0,0,255),3)
          cv.putText(output, "rectangle "+str(x)+" , " +str(y-5), (x, y-5), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0))
          

minr=int(17*width/192)
maxr=int(7*width/64)
mind=int(width//5)


print("start",start_x,start_y)
print("width",width)
print("height",height)
print("minr", minr)
print("maxr",maxr)
print("mind",mind)

gray = cv.medianBlur(gray, 5)
circles = cv.HoughCircles(gray, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, mind,param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=minr, maxRadius=maxr)

detected_circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

for (x, y ,r) in detected_circles[0, :]:
    if(y>start_y and x>start_x):
        
        print("center ", x,y)
        idx= int (((x-start_x)*8)//width) 
        exp=int(4- (0.5* (idx+1)))
        n+= 2**exp
        cv.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 0, 0), 3)
        cv.circle(output, (x, y), 2, (0, 255, 255), 3)
print(n)
cv.imshow('output',output)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

This works perfectly, for all the images of this type. However, there is a slight drawback:

The test images are in a very "nice" format: all are of fixed width and height, all are perfectly upright, all the colours for the rectangle and circle in each image are of exactly the same shade in all the images, etc.

However, we were supposed to make a code a bit more general: in order to accommodate "not so nice" images also. For example, images of this style:

[image]

Essentially the same format, but the background lighting + the stand not being perfectly upright makes it slightly more challenging to generalize the code, I feel. This is why I refrained from using HSV colour masking, because there wont be a set of higher and lower values that would fit all the images.

However, what I tried to do is also failing: its not able to detect the rectangle properly. I expected it to detect multiple rectangles, but its detecting rectangles at those locations, where there aren't any at all (and not at the locations where there are rectangles).

**How can I tweak my code to make it a bit more general, in order to also process the second type of image properly?**

Comment: discard HoughCircles completely. it's useless here. do not use it. you have the rectangle. you know the circles are in fixed positions. sample those positions (take subregion, calculate mean color) and decide if it's blue or green (also sample the rectangle itself for a baseline green measurement!)

Comment: Threshold on blue using cv2.inRange. Then get the contours. Test if circular if you need to. Then use cv2.minEnclosingCircle to get the centers and radii and test those if needed. Why do you need to find the green rectangle? If you do, threshold on green to find the green, then crop the rectangle and threshold again on blue inside the rectangle.

Comment: Do you know the dictionary that the aruco tag is generated from? OpenCV's aruco detection is fast and mostly reliable. We could use it to check the relative locations of where the four circles could be and see if those spots are mostly blue or not.