# grayscale image causing inaccuracies in HoughCircles() method

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

This is a follow-up to [openCV polygon detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67861533/opencv-polygon-detection). For the second image, I wasn't getting any rectangles detected, but that was because my threshold values weren't correct for that image.

I used otsu thresholding, and added a constraint to remove small and other irrelevant rectangles that got detected.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import math

img = cv.imread("t1.jpeg")



n=0

#rectangle parameters
width=0 
height=0

start_x=0 
start_y=0
end_x=0 
end_y=0

#houghcircles parameters     
minr=0 
maxr=0
mind=0

maxarea=0
area=0

output = img.copy()
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret2,th = cv.threshold(gray,0,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY+cv.THRESH_OTSU)



#rectangle detection

contours, _ = cv.findContours(th, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for contour in contours:

    approx = cv.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.01* cv.arcLength(contour, True), True)
    
    cv.drawContours(img, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 0), 5)
    
    x = approx.ravel()[0]
    y = approx.ravel()[1]

    x1 ,y1, w, h = cv.boundingRect(approx)
    a=w*h    
    if len(approx) == 4 and x>15  :
            
        aspectRatio = float(w)/h
        if  aspectRatio >= 2.5 and a>50:          
          print(x1,y1,w,h)
          width=w
          height=h   
          start_x=x1
          start_y=y1
          end_x=start_x+width
          end_y=start_y+height      
          cv.rectangle(output, (start_x,start_y), (end_x,end_y), (0,0,255),3)
          cv.putText(output, "rectangle "+str(x1)+" , " +str(y1-5), (x1, y1-5), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0))
        

minr=int(17*width/192)
maxr=int(7*width/64)
mind=int(width//5)


print("start",start_x,start_y)
print("width",width)
print("height",height)
print("minr", minr)
print("maxr",maxr)
print("mind",mind)

cv.imshow("op1",output)

#circle detection,converting binary to decimal.

circles = cv.HoughCircles(gray, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, mind,param1=50, param2=20, minRadius=minr, maxRadius=maxr)
detected_circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

for (x, y ,r) in detected_circles[0, :]:
    if(y>start_y and x>start_x and y<start_y+height and x<start_x+width):
        
        cf= ((x-start_x)*8)/width
        fp= cf-math.floor(cf)
        
        
        if(fp>0.50):
            idx=math.ceil(cf)
        else:
            idx=math.floor(cf)

        
        
        exp=int(4- (0.5* (idx+1)))
       
        n+= 2**exp
        print("circle",x,y,r)
        cv.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 0, 0), 3)
        cv.circle(output, (x, y), 2, (0, 255, 255), 3)
        
print(n)
cv.imshow("th",th)
cv.imshow("gray",gray)
cv.imshow('output',output)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

The final result was this:

[image]

Now the rectangle was detected successfully, however the circle wasn't detected properly. The detected circles are roughly of the same size as the target circle, which means the parameters for HoughCircles() are correct, although the circle wasn't detected at the correct location.

This is probably because the glare results in the circle almost disappearing in the grayscale image (which I used in the HoughCircles() method):

[image]

What can I do to use the HoughCircles() method for this image?

edit: Fixed a minor error in the code. The problem still persists, however i tested with other images, and it worked with the one where the grayscale image was decent enough:
[image]

Comment: convert to LAB and threshold on the B channel to get the blue circle. In the B channel it will be darker than the rest.

Comment: what is LAB and how do I threshold on the blue channel? Im sorry, Im a bit new to openCV

Comment: LAB is a colorspace. You can convert to it from `lab=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)`. Then you can separate the B channel as `b = lab[:,:,2]`. Then threshold on it using inRangle() for blue as `thresh = cv2.inRange(b, lowcolor, highcolor)` where lowcolor is the low end of the range of colors for the color in the B channel and high color is color at the high end of the range of colors for it in the B channel. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981

Comment: Actually, since we separate the B channel, all one needs to do is threshold on the darkest colors with a simple threshold, I think.

Comment: may I suggest doing screenshots using the "print screen" key on the keyboard, rather than literally taking a picture of the screen?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz understandable. However, I already had these pictures on the phone so I thought Ill use them... Ill be careful next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to extract the circle in Python/OpenCV. Convert to LAB, separate the B channel, then threshold on the dark circle.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load images
img = cv2.imread('4_sign.jpg')

# convert to LAB
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

# separate B channel
b = lab[:,:,2]

# threshold and invert
thresh = cv2.threshold(b, 105, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = 255 - thresh

# apply morphology to clean it up
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get min enclosing circle
# numpy points are (y,x), so need to transpose
points = np.argwhere(morph.transpose()>0)

center, radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(points)
print('center:', center, 'radius:', radius)

# draw circle on copy of input
result = img.copy()
cx = int(round(center[0]))
cy = int(round(center[1]))
rr = int(round(radius))
cv2.circle(result, (cx,cy), rr, (255,255,255), 2)

# save output
cv2.imwrite('4_sign_circle.jpg', result)

# display results
cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh)
cv2.imshow('morph',morph)
cv2.imshow('result',result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

**ADDITION**

Here is a version using HoughCircles.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load images
img = cv2.imread('4_sign.jpg')
ht, wd = img.shape[:2]
minhw = min(ht,wd)

# convert to LAB
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

# separate B channel
b = lab[:,:,2]

# threshold and invert
thresh = cv2.threshold(b, 105, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = 255 - thresh

# apply morphology to clean it up
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get circle from HoughCircles
min_dist = int(minhw/20)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(morph, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist=min_dist, param1=100, param2=10, minRadius=30, maxRadius=60)
#print(circles)

result = img.copy()
for circle in circles[0]:
    # draw the circle on copy of input
    (x,y,r) = circle
    center = (x,y)
    radius = r
    print('center:', center, 'radius:', radius)
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    cv2.circle(result, center, radius, (255, 255, 255), 2)

# save output
cv2.imwrite('4_sign_circle2.jpg', result)

# display results
cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh)
cv2.imshow('morph',morph)
cv2.imshow('result',result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]

Textual Information:

```
center: (410.5, 686.5) radius: 54.4
```

Comment: Can I find the radius of the circle using this method?

Comment: Not directly. You need to do either hough circle detection or use cv2.minEnclosingCircle or cv2.fitEllipse.

Comment: I have modified my answer to include extracting the circle dimensions using minEnclosingCircle. My new resulting image has a white circle around the blue region.

Comment: this is a good answer , but my main question is still unanswered... I want use the hough circles method. I was wondering if instead of the grayscale image I can use something else as the appropriate parameter for the houghCircles() method.

Comment: As I said above, you can do the same but in place of minEnclosingCircle you can use Hough circles. So use the B channel of the LAB conversion as your grayscale image and do your HoughCircles.

Comment: I have added a version of my code that uses HoughCircles for you in my answer above.